# Echo image file in tag <img src=""> in php

Tags: php, html

A little problem. Please help me. I just want to echo the ROW image of each id in my database.

here is part of my php code

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // Print out the contents of the entry 
    echo "<img src='. $row["image1"] .'>";
    }
```

Can anyone help? Please and thank you

Comment: Code highlight shows your problem.

Comment: what? @u_mulder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this.First take your image in variable and then define `src` of your image.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // Print out the contents of the entry 
    $image = $row['image1'];
    echo "<img src='".$image."'>";
    }
```

Comment: Because your code __obvioulsy__ has syntax errors. And code hightlight shows where.

Comment: Hi sir it works thank you, but please explain if you answer a question. Thank you.

Comment: just short a double quotation in after the equals and apostrophe

Comment: There is a clear syntax error in echo line. Correct is  echo "<img src='".$image."'>";

Answer (score -1):

The original question has syntax errors caused by incorrect placement of the single and double quote marks.

PHP allows you to insert variables such as `$variable` and also `$someArray['variable']` directly inside **double** quoted strings by enclosing it in curly braces `{` and `}`.

When generating HTML, I prefer to create HTML markup that uses double quotes for attributes.

So using the curly brace syntax you can rewrite the code from the question as follows:

1) With double quotes for the src="" attribute escape them with backslashes

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    echo "<img src=\"{$row['image1']}\">";
}
```

2) If you are not bothered about using double quotes for your HTML attributes then you can simplify to

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    echo "<img src='{$row['image1']}'>";
}
```

Alternatively, without the curly brace technique you just need to get the order of the single and double quotes correct, so all of the following are also valid:

```
echo "<img src=\"" . $row['image1'] . "\">";

echo '<img src="' . $row['image1'] . '">';

echo '<img src=\'' . $row['image1'] . '\'>';
```

Finally you can do the least desirable method IMHO which is to directly inline the variable inside a double quoted string. This only works with normal variables and not arrays.

```
$image = $row['image1'];
echo "<img src=\"$image\">";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!